# Php dynamic url change

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have **< a href = "index.php?state=0">state</ a >**
On each click I want to toggle the state value
Suppose it's now index.php?state=0 next click it will be index.pho?state=1 and so on. How can I achieve this using php or vanilla javascript

Comment: Welcome! is this work for all users or a individual user?

Answer (score 0):

Offbit, but you can try something like this

```
<a href = "index.php?state=0" id="mya">state</a>
```

```
var st = 1

document.getElementById("mya").addEventListener('click', function(){
    var lnk = document.getElementById("mya");

    window.open(
      lnk.href,
      '_blank'
    );

    lnk.innerHTML = "State";
    lnk.setAttribute('href', "index.php?state="+st);
    st++;

    return false;
});
```